# The set where $|g|>\|g\|_{L^\infty}$ has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence  of functions in $L^\infty$ where $f_{n}\longrightarrow f\in L^{\infty}$. Set $E_{n_0} = \{x \in [0,1],  |f_{n_{0}}(x) - f(x)| > \|f_{n_0} - f\|_{L^\infty}\}$ for some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Somebody have some hints to calculate $m(E_{n_{0}})$?

Comment: The definition of $\| \cdot \|_{L^\infty}$ tells you that it is zero...

Comment: @Ian $\|f\|_{L^\infty}=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\{f(x)\}$ because $f\in L_\infty$ is bounded. This means $E_{n_0}=\emptyset$

Comment: That's not quite true. When $f$ is a function (not an equivalence class of functions) $\| f \|_{L^\infty}$ is in general not the supremum of $|f|$ but rather the essential supremum of $|f|$. Formally, $\| f \|_{L^\infty} = \inf \left  \{ a : m \left ( |f|^{-1}((a,\infty)) \right ) = 0 \right \}$. The supremum is greater than or equal to the essential supremum, and strict inequality can happen in many cases. For example the essential supremum of $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is zero while the supremum is $1$.

Comment: Note also that the essential supremum is invariant with respect to a.e. equivalence, while the supremum is not. In other words, if $g=0$ a.e. then $\text{ess } \sup f+g = \text{ess } \sup f$.

Comment: I Got You, but i can't see how this implies $m(E_{n_0})=0$.

Comment: If the inf I wrote above is attained, then you're done. You should argue that even if the inf is not attained, $m(E_{n_0})$ is still zero. You can do this by arguing that it is less than $\varepsilon$ for each $\varepsilon>0$, which you can do using the definition of infimum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g=f_{n_0}-f$. By definition, $\|g\|_{L^\infty}$ is the infimum of all number $t$ such that the set $\{|g|>t\}$ has measure zero. Since
$$
\{g>\|g\|_{L^\infty}\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{ g>\|g\|_{L^\infty} + 1/n\}
$$
and the countable union of sets of measure zero has measure zero, the conclusion follows.